# How to do rsync with different destination port

Tags: debian, backup, rsync

I'm trying to `rsync` between two hosts. The source host has SSH keys in the destination server and I verified it can ssh without a password. The destination server is allowing ssh over port 2209.

When performing the below command in the source host I'm just prompt with a `>` by bash and nothing happens:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 2209” /var/www/ root@DESTINATION_IP:/srv/OLD_backup
```

Also tried other variations:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 2209” root@DESTINATION_IP:/srv/OLD_backup /var/www/

rsync -avz /var/www/ -e "ssh -p 2209” root@DESTINATION_IP:/srv/OLD_backup
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I needed to use single quotes when specifying the ssh:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 2209' /var/www/ root@DESTINATION_IP:/srv/OLD_backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command has a mix of plain ASCII quotes (the kind you want at the command line) and fancy Unicode quotes (which the shell doesn't recognize). Specifically, the `"ssh -p 2209”` part starts with a plain quote and ends with a fancy quote.